# Django models and database synchronization

Tags: django

I have a theorethical question, how to synchronize models changes with database when adding or removing an attribute?

Comment: People usually tend to use Django-South for db shema migration.

Answer (score 2):

You mean data migration?

You need [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)

> South, intelligent schema and data migrations for ​Django projects.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are [many ways to migrate the database schema](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/20833599582/django-schema-migrations-nashvegas-vs-south-vs).

Nashvegas is, imho, a nice alternative.